# Dragging and dropping an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use a `draggable` and `droppable` plugins of `jquery ui`. I want to trigger a

`drop event` of `droppable plugin` by dragging and dropping the elements helper clone. How can i do this?

You can see the example here : [See the Codiqa (drag & drop)](http://www.jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: I'm not getting the question.

Comment: Please put a sample code for your problem on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I want to trigger the drop event of droppable without dropping the element itself ( by using the helper option of draggable )

Comment: You are using Jquery UI and the link given in question if jquerymobile? ):

Comment: Just see the drag and drop example of `codiqa` application in the JQM link. There the element which we are dragging is not actually drag just the helper clone is dragging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a draggable element with helper option, and append the clone of draggable element when it's dropped.

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#dropzone").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
        }
    });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bLTFa/)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider giving the jQuery UI documentation a shot(http://jqueryui.com/demos/), it's great!

You have plenty of examples both for [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/).

By looking through the documentation it seems draggable have an stop event.

> Supply a callback function to handle the stop event as an init option.
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).draggable({
>    stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
> });
> ```
>
> Bind to the stop event by type: dragstop.
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).bind( "dragstop", function(event, ui) {
>   ...
> });
> ```

that should suffice for triggering any desired event.